# Dynamically build a type-hinted dict from a PostGreSQL DB read

Tags: python, psycopg2, type-hinting

Using python, PostGreSQL and psycopg2 to bridge the two.

Currently building the CRUD functions. Crux of this question is on the Reads. Normally, the cursor fetch functions return data packaged in a tuple. For readability's sake, I want to repackage everything in a dictionary. (XY Problem: Should I not do this?)

Using cursor.description, I can pull the name and type of each column. But what kind of structure can I use that will hold both a label and type?

pool_settings being str, int, int, int.

```py
def read_pool_settings(site):
    connection = create_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        f'''
        SELECT * FROM pool_settings
        WHERE site = '{site}';
        ''')
    output = cursor.fetchone()
    column_info = [(desc[0], desc[1]) for desc in cursor.description]
    connection.close()
    dict_output = dict()
    for index, info in enumerate(column_info):
        dict_output[info[0]] = output[index]
        # something about type hinting with info[1] here
    return dict_output
```

I know you can use dict[str, union(str, int)] to indicate a dict of str keys and str/int values, but I want each key to be type hinted (so my IDE can remind me on hover, not really for compiling debugging)

I've also looked into typing.TypedDict, but you need to manually declare types and it does not apply to my needs.

Is this just a lost cause in python?

Comment: You can get dicts using one of the built [connection/cursor subclasses](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#cursor-subclasses), either `psycopg2.extras.DictCursor` or `psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor`.

Comment: There is no single place in your code where field names (and types, of course) are mentioned. Static type checking is **static**. I can't even imagine a `mypy` plugin that connects to your database, builds TypedDict's for every table and then finds and parses all raw SQL strings to assign the types. It must be fragile, broken in many corner cases and use very deep magic. Maybe you can use `sqlalchemy` to write models explicitly (and then use ORM instead of raw SQL, at least for standard tasks) instead?